# Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent

Tags: magento2.4, class, custom-extension

I am trying to extend the \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface class and my construct looks like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
    \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory)
{
    $this->_curl = $curl;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
```

I am getting an error though on this line return parent::__construct($context);

> Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent.

How else should I write the return line then?

Comment: What does your class definition look like, i.e. the part where you extend the HttpPostActionInterface class?

Comment: ```class submitForm extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface```

Comment: I see you are confusing this as an interface how do you extend it . you are using class to create an extension for an interface

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `extend` \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface because it's an interface. You can `implement` it - in this case parent constructor calling is impossible.

I guess you need to extend certain action class instead of general interface.

Comment: So if I implement it then this line throws an error about the parent:: scope...how do I fix that: ```return parent::__construct($context);```

Comment: just remove this line. Looks like you need to learn how interfaces works in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface` you implement it. Since this is an interface, you cannot extend